# Extjs4, What is the lazyRender?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

What is the lazyRender in Extjs?

I couldn't find about that in Extjs document, also I couldn't find any web pages that describe about lazyRender.

May I ask a good example please?

Thanks!

Comment: One question per post, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lazyRender` is a config option. Set it to `true` to prevent the ComboBox from rendering until requested (should always be used when rendering into an Ext.Editor (e.g. Grids), defaults to false).

This is from version 3.x but the usage is the same with version 4.x.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-cfg-lazyRender

Comment: Thank you, I wonder why the default value is false if it should always be used. (\ /)

Comment: @Expertwannabe, the documentation says it should always be used _when rendering into an Ext.Editor_. For a standalone ComboBox (i.e. **not** in an Ext.Editor), it may make sense to leave lazyRender as false.